# Use date-fns formatting style in php using Carbon

Tags: javascript, php, php-carbon, date-fns

I have an app where my users can enter a format string for a date object. I use date-fns to format the dates (with [this format](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format)) and it works perfectly on the front end:

```js
import { format } from "date-fns";
import { es } from "date-fns/locale";

const formatStr = "yyyy-MM-dd" // user defined
format(date, formatStr, { locale: es }); // returns "2022-03-23"
```

The problem is that now I have to use the same format in php. I thought Carbon would do the job, but it actually uses [php date formatting style](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

```php
$formatStr = "yyyy-MM-dd"; // same value as before
Carbon::parse($date)->format($formatStr) // returns "22222222-MarMar-2323"
```

Is there any way to "translate" date-fns formatting style to Carbon, or should I use another library?

Comment: What is `date-fns` formatting style? What does `$formatStr` contain?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `date-fns` uses [this formatting style](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format).

Comment: Carbon is based on PHP's [DateTime class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeinterface.php) so uses the same formatting flags. They have some [extra formatting options](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting), but nothing that appears to use the style you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. Carbon has an `isoFormat()`, which apparently offers that format. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization has a bit of information on it, where it talks about internationalization.

Comment: I'll check that information, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Carbon has an `isoFormat()` that accepts a momentjs-style string. From their  [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization):

> ->isoFormat(string $format): string use ISO format rather than PHP-specific format and use inner translations rather than language packages you need to install on every machine where you deploy your application. isoFormat method is compatible with momentjs format method, it means you can use same format strings as you may have used in moment from front-end or node.js. Here are some examples:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2018-06-15 17:34:15.984512', 'UTC');
echo $date->isoFormat('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 15th 2018, 5:34:15 pm
echo "\n";
echo $date->isoFormat('dddd');           // Friday
echo "\n";
echo $date->isoFormat('MMM Do YY');      // Jun 15th 18
echo "\n";
echo $date->isoFormat('YYYY [escaped] YYYY'); // 2018 escaped 2018
```

So you should be able to use

```
Carbon::parse($date)->isoFormat($formatStr)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but isoFormat doesn't work with the example I used on my question. Using `yyyy-MM-dd` returns `yyyy-03-We`.

Comment: Ah, okay. It's apparently based more on [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) than Unicode, so not all of the formats are there. The Carbon doc I linked does have all of the available formats, so it has `YYYY`, but not `yyyy`

Comment: Yes, I might switch from `date-fns` to another library that uses the ISO standard for formatting.